# How to get wordpress post author email in qoutes

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to get wordpress post author email in a quote like "myeamil@live.com" on single.php page.

Actually I wanna send email to that author who posted this post.

I am using wp_mail function to send email to author from single.php page.

Here is the variable i am using but it is getting admin email.

```
$emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
```

Instead of admin email I want author email who posted the post. I need help please. Many thanks.

**Update**

Here is my code i am trying to do

> if(!isset($hasError)) { //$emailTo = "w_chand@live.com"; if
>   (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){ $emailTo =
>   the_author_meta('user_email'); } $subject = 'email subject goes
>   here'.$name; $body = " Name: $Name  nnDuration: $duration  nnComments:
>   $comments ";
>
> $headers = "Reply-To: '".$name."'  rn"; if(wp_mail($emailTo,
>   $subject, $body, $headers)){
>
> echo "Enquiry has been sent successfully";
>   } else { echo "Mail function Error!"; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get by **get_the_author_meta()** wordpress function to get author email address.

```
<?php 
      $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email');
?>
```

Get the email address for user ID 25, and echo it using their display name as the anchor text.

```
<p>Email the author: 
     <a href="mailto: 
          <?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_email', 25); ?>"
     >
          <?php the_author_meta('display_name', 25); ?>
     </a>
</p>
```

---

Following function is ***deprecated***,

```
 <?php the_author_email(); ?>
```

#### Mailto Link

Displays author email address as a "mailto" link.

```
<a href="mailto:<?php the_author_email(); ?>">Contact the author</a>
```

#### Demo Code

```
<div id="about-author-wrap">
     <div class="about-author-avatar">
        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '90' ); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="about-author-info">                                
        <h5>About the Post Writer <small>View all posts by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="about-author-description">
        <?php the_author_meta("description"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you.But it is logged in user email. Actually it should author email who posted.

Comment: so you want to get author email via logged on user email address.

Comment: According to you it is `<?php $emailTo = the_author_email(); ?>` and how i get output in quotes in order to sending email?

Comment: When you careate a Post template at that time you post body end part you set author information on that time you can set this emial address by using this.

Comment: I know.I just want quotes to send up email.

Comment: You want to send email to author from your wordpress.

Comment: Exactly from single.php page in wordpress.

Comment: as per my knowledge you can not set email on single.php page. but another way i would recommended to you create sidebar widgets for feedback from.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. [Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta#Get_A_User.27s_Email_Address). Hope it helps.

```
<?php $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $emailTo = '"'.the_author_meta('user_email').'"';
```

Comment: Thanks. I did and getting `Mail function Error!`

Comment: Please use single quotes for all the data like this:

wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', 'The message' );

Therefore for $emailTo, try this:

$emailTo = "'".the_author_meta('user_email')."'";

Comment: I did bro. Still mail function error. I am stuck with it :(